# How to configure PHP mail on Windows (Perhaps to use mail from Ubuntu Dev Server)

Tags: php, windows, email, configuration, ubuntu

I am working locally on my widnows development machine. I have access to a Ubuntu server in office too. How can I configure PHP to send mail from Windows? Else, how can I configure it to use the Ubuntu Server that I know can send mail? Where can I know the URL, need for passwords etc?

On Ubuntu, I am used postfix

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have a built in mail server. You can install one, or just relay mail through another mail server.

Comment: Yes, so I want to relay mail from my Ubuntu server, how can I do that? Do I just use the domain name/IP? http://www.pastie.org/2064746 doesnt appear to work still

Comment: The server has to be set up to relay mail. You have to be careful with how you do that. The last thing you want to create is an open relay. Server fault would be a good place to ask about postfix configurations.